# How to hide JSP generated text field using javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, xml, jsp, xmi

```
JSP CODE

<%= formData.displayField("ABCDRADIO", true) %>
        <div id="show" style="display:none"><%= formData.displayField("ABCD_DESC", true)%></div>
        <%if((formData.getValue("ABCDRADIO").equals("Y") )) {%>
        <script>showDesc("Y");</script>
        <% }else{ %>
        <script>showDesc("N");</script>
        <% } %>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE :

```
  function showDesc(mode)
    {
        alert("Called");
        if(mode==="N"){
        document.getElementById('show').style.display="none";}
        else{
        document.getElementById('show').style.display="block";}
    }
```

I am generating radio button through a framework by calling the associated XML. But I cannot do Hide and show using that. I want to show ADCD_DESC text field when radio button is Y and hide it when N. The javascript function is getting called but the field is still being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you hide directly using server-side `if` statement in your jsp?

```
<%= formData.displayField("ABCDRADIO", true) %>
<div id='show'
     style='display:<%=formData.getValue("ABCDRADIO").equals("Y")?"block":"none"%>'
  <%= formData.displayField("ABCD_DESC", true)%>
</div>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: actually I tried doing that with server side if but the problem is to bring that into action I had to reload the page again and again to see the effect which is not my requirement. I want to get the effect dynamically being on the same page. It is still not working.

Comment: Could you attach event javascript-side? Do you know the ID of your checkbox? Could you post your HTML code?

Comment: Solved it by overwriting the radio button and text area and declaring event using JSP . Thanks for the help..:)